# navigationController.setToolbarHidden doesn't work if switching back and forth between views

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I have a `UIViewController` and a `UITableViewController`: `A` and `B`, respectively. `A` is connected to `B` with a push segue.
`B` contains a button which, when pressed, toggles the ability to select rows in `B`'s `tableView`. When the user is selecting rows, the bottom toolbar appears with a set of buttons.

My problem is that if I press the select button so that the toolbar is showing, and then press the back button to go back to `A` and then go to `B` again. When I then press the select button, the toolbar doesn't show, even though "flag2" is printed in the console.

```
@IBAction func selectButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if isSelecting {
        print("flag1")
        selectButton.setTitle("Select", for: .normal)
        navigationController?.setToolbarHidden(true, animated: true)
    }
    else {
        print("flag2")
        selectButton.setTitle("Cancel", for: .normal)
        navigationController?.setToolbarHidden(false, animated: true)
    }
    isSelecting = !isSelecting
}
```

Comment: I've only set the toolbar hidden (or not) in viewWillAppear, which tells me that the view, uh, will appear. Maybe try adding **view.setNeedsDisplay()**?

Comment: @dfd Thanks for the answer, but it doesn't seem to work. I also tried calling `view.setNeedsLayout()`, `view.setNeedsFocusUpdate()`, and `view.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()`. None of which worked.